# How to remove 'by [author]' from Genesis Framework

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am using Genesis framework for my new website, everything is fine but I can't find a way to remove `by [author]` below the entry title. I don't want to hide it using CSS, I want to completely remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Genesis Framework website says to add this to your child theme's functions.php file. I tested this and it works great.

```
//* Remove the post info function    
remove_action( 'genesis_before_post_content', 'genesis_post_info' );
```